# Prove that $\log(n!)\leq(\log(n))!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, asymptotics, factorial

Prove that $\log(n!)\leq(\log(n))!$

---

My attempt:

I read somewhere that $n\leq\log(n!)\leq(\log(n))!$. But when I used calculator $\log(n!)$ can not be less than or equal to $(\log(n))!$.

> > Can you explain it in a formal way, please?

Comment: If you meant $\;\left(\log n\right)!\;$ then this number can only be taken via the Gamma Function, as it usually isn't a natural number. Did you mean this? Or perhaps there's a floor function there?

Comment: Yes, $(\log(n))!$

Comment: @Joanpemo I think it does not make great difference when $n$ is large. The bound is quite loose.

Comment: @user3313320 Thank you, I agree with you. It's only to have an idea of what can be assumed for a possible answer to the asker.

Comment: To be precise we should either write $\lfloor log(n) \rfloor !$ or $\Gamma(log(n) + 1)$ but I don't think it'll really matter.

Comment: @Joanpemo It's okay. IMHO assuming it is the Gamma Function is more natural, for the sake of continuity.

Comment: I do think that the way to go here is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation . Note that the first inequality is an immediate consequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\log(n)$

$\log(n!)<\log(n^n)=n\log(n)=xe^x$
$(\log(n))!=x!$

and the results follow by **Factorial grows faster than Exponential**.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

As I suggested, using Strirling approximation is a *very* loose way, one immediately gets
$$\log(n!)\approx n\log  n$$
and
$$\log(n)! \approx (\log(n))^{\log(n)}.$$
Cleraly the second dominates the first term, giving the claim.

Comment: Please, clear little bit this $$\log(n)! \sim (\log(n))^{\log(n)}.$$

Comment: Just set $n=\log n$ in Stirling's formula $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ and forget about the other terms

Comment: What is interesting (at least to me) is that $\log(x!) \gt \log(x)!$ holds if $x \gt 2.24836$.

Comment: Wait... If what you claim *is* true, then this should contradict what I am saying... or would it?

Comment: @b00nheT I think you are correct. Put some numbers much larger to check it. This inequality describes asymptotic behavior so some small numbers may contradict the result.

Comment: Yeah... maybe you are right... But judging from WA graph https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma(%5Clog(n)%2B1)-%5Clog(Gamma(n%2B1)) it would really look like it is the other way around, or at least up to some *large* n. Indeed, The turnpoint is at about $n=1500$, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma(%5Clog(n)%2B1)-%5Clog(Gamma(n%2B1))%3D0

Comment: Interesting ! So, the inequality holds if $2.24836 \lt x\lt 1489.0263$. Amazing, indeed ! Your turn : plot the function for $1\leq x\leq 3$. Cheers.

Comment: The notation $\sim$ has a [specific definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition), so your statement $\log(n)! \sim (\log(n))^{\log(n)}$ is true if by "and forget about the other terms" you mean "and abuse the notation $\sim$".

Comment: Absolutely. This is also why I wrote "very loosely". I know about the notation, maybe I should have used something of the form $\approx$ instead. I am sorry about that. But I didn't want to keep all the other terms, which are asymptotically of lower importance